# HTTPRequest and save the file locally into iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, save

how do i do a HTTPRequest and then save the File locally into the iPad/iPhone.
Im working with the simulator right now so is it possible to emulate the local data storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is really easy to do, and I wrote another answer on how to do it: [How to download files directly to disk on the iPhone os?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868549/how-to-download-files-directly-to-disk-on-the-iphone-os/2868765#2868765)

Comment: alright i'll take a look and see whether if i am able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

ASIHTTPRequest might also come in handy here as an intelligent wrapper to HTTP functionality:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/