# downloading images from url

Tags: iphone

How to download images programmatically in iphone and to store the in image library . I am able to download single image and to store it in iphone library from a web url. How to do that with multiple images.my aim is just to download images (multiple images ) from url and to save it in photo library.

Comment: You should accept more answers so people will be more inclined to answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your single Url contain a Xml or json response and you have to parse that..other wise using single url you cant fetch multiple data..Any way refer this..[Custom Url connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868549/how-to-download-files-directly-to-disk-on-the-iphone-os)

Answer (score 0):

How can it be possible, by using one URL, you can see only one image in browser. The same way your code will also work. For multiple images, zip them on server, download that zip, extract on your device and add to library. 
Else create as many url requests as number of images to download.